# GA4 is recording lesser Ecommerce purchase count? (upto 20 to 30% Less) is it normal? What is standard here?

Tags: e-commerce, analytics, data-conversion, google-analytics-4

Is it normal to get lesser ecommerce purchase data accuracy in GA4 (even lesser upto 20 to 30%) comparing the data base record? What is standard here? Also please mention the reason of the record and tracking discrepency.

To get the understanding

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most obvious reason is adblockers. They would block your tracking.

The percentage depends on the likeliness of particular audience to block it. We generally expect it to be around 10%, but, as an example, it can reach even 50% when you look at the STEM student traffic.

Other common issue is poorly implemented tracking. Which, in the case of conversions, is more likely to double count the conversions rather than undercount them, but that is possible too.

Finally, GA4's interface is still not a very reliable tool to access your data, so you may take a glance at it in BQ if you're friendly with SQL just to make sure what you're seeing in a GA4 interface is really what's in data.